# Installing pygrib Package

Tags: python, windows, installation, grib, pygrib

Apologies in advance for what is probably a bad/poorly phrased question, but I merely dabble in programming and am very unfamiliar with under the hood aspects of package installation, etc.

Basically, I am trying to install the pygrib package (available here: https://github.com/jswhit/pygrib) via a cygwin terminal.

I am running Python 2.7.3 32-bit on Windows 10.

Originally I encountered the missing vcvarsall.bat error the first time I tried to run 'python seteup.py build' and followed the advice here: [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

After installing the MS Visual Studio package, I have made it past that error and to another I do not understand with the following output:

```
$ python setup.py build
reading from setup.cfg...running build
running build_py
running build_ext
skipping 'pygrib.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'pygrib' extension

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -I/usr/local\include -I/usr/local\include -I/usr/local\include/jasper -I/usr/local\include -I/usr\include -I/usr\include -Ig2clib_src -IC:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda2\include -IC:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda2\PC /Tcpygrib.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pygrib.obj
pygrib.c
c:\users\matthew\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
pygrib.c(242) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'grib_api.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Obviously it's still looking for some other files, or needs other environment variables defined, but I'm at a loss as to how to proceed and I'm far from an expert when it comes to any of this.

I'd also be glad to try something completely different if you have a better way to go about this process entirely.

I have tried pip and the conda installer, but have not had any luck with them either.

Thank you in advance for anything you can offer.

Comment: did you install the `grib api library` and `pyproj module`?

Answer (score 7):

Better to use linux on virtual machine within Windows ten. Then you can install `pygrib` without pain. As you are trying to play with meteorological data, it is recommended to install Linux and it will help you at may places. There is even Anaconda has a package (only for Linux and Mac). You can install using:-

`conda install -c conda-forge pygrib=2.0.1`

For your specif case following link might be useful:-

https://github.com/jswhit/pygrib/issues/19

https://github.com/jswhit/pygrib/pull/18 and https://github.com/conda-forge/ecmwf_grib-feedstock/issues/5

Gud luck.

Comment: Amazing, lost 30 mins before finding this answer!

Answer (score 6):

for python 3 i needed to install it directly with linux package manager

```
sudo apt-get install python3-grib
```

Comment: Took me a while to find this, didn't realize there was such a simple way to install pygrib on linux.

Comment: How did you get python to recognize this? I still get 'no module named pygrib'

Comment: also if you run your script in the shell? ``python3 myscript.py``

Answer (score 3):

To use: `pip install pygrib`
you need to install python3-grib:
`sudo apt install python3-grib`

NOTE:
Ubuntu Linux: 
python3-grib requires libeccodes-dev 
if later you install libgrib-api-dev it requires libgrib-api-dev.
which is not compatable with libgrib-api-dev
Meaning, if you install libgrib-api-dev after you install python3-grib you break the python3-grib installation.

Answer (score 1):

Take me a while also, but this way was very simple and efficient. I then installed it on pycharm.
and on anaconda  with

- pip install pyproj
- pip install pygrib

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) on Windows 10.

I have accessed Anaconda Prompt for the environment that I wanted to install the package.

In there, I have started by installing `pyproj`:

```
pip install pyproj
```

And then:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pygrib
```