# Install pygrip and conda forge

Tags: python, conda, pygrib

I am trying to install pygrib to extract some data from grib1 files. I found this: [Installing pygrib Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640117/installing-pygrib-package) answer that recommended using conda-forge. Which I didn't know existed. Anyway, I made a new environment and used the `conda install -c conda-forge pygrib=2.0.1` command. It seems to have installed everything fine (I have `pygrib  2.0.1 . py35_3 . conda-forge` listed when I call `conda list` So it seems to have installed everything. But when I `import pygrib` I'm getting a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygrib'` error. Is there something I have to do to activate the package? I was under the impression it would be good to go when I ran the conda-forge command.

```
# packages in environment at /Users/maxcaudle/anaconda3/envs/grib:
#
appnope                   0.1.0                     <pip>
backcall                  0.1.0                     <pip>
bzip2                     1.0.6                         1    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2018.4.16                     0    conda-forge
certifi                   2018.4.16                py35_0    conda-forge
curl                      7.61.0               h93b3f91_1    conda-forge
decorator                 4.3.0                     <pip>
ecmwf_grib                1.27.0               h0cee55e_1    conda-forge
hdf4                      4.2.13                        0    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.2               hc401514_1    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2018.0.3                      0
ipython                   6.5.0                     <pip>
ipython-genutils          0.2.0                     <pip>
jasper                    1.900.1                       4    conda-forge
jedi                      0.12.1                    <pip>
jpeg                      9c                   h470a237_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.14.6                        0    conda-forge
libcxx                    4.0.1                h579ed51_0
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hebd6815_0
libedit                   3.1.20170329         hb402a30_2
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2
libnetcdf                 4.6.1                h039f2a5_4    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.2.20               hdc02c5d_7
libpng                    1.6.35               ha92aebf_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.8.0                h5b517e9_2    conda-forge
mkl                       2018.0.3                      1
mkl_fft                   1.0.5                    py35_0    conda-forge
mkl_random                1.0.1                    py35_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_0
numpy                     1.14.3           py35h9bb19eb_2
numpy-base                1.14.3           py35h7ef55bc_1
openssl                   1.0.2o               h470a237_1    conda-forge
parso                     0.3.1                     <pip>
pexpect                   4.6.0                     <pip>
pickleshare               0.7.4                     <pip>
pip                       18.0                     py35_1    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            1.0.15                    <pip>
ptyprocess                0.6.0                     <pip>
Pygments                  2.2.0                     <pip>
pygrib                    2.0.1                    py35_3    conda-forge
pyproj                    1.9.5.1                  py35_0    conda-forge
python                    3.5.5                h0a44026_3
readline                  7.0                  hc1231fa_4
setuptools                40.0.0                   py35_1    conda-forge
simplegeneric             0.8.1                     <pip>
six                       1.11.0                    <pip>
sqlite                    3.24.0               ha441bb4_0
tk                        8.6.7                h35a86e2_3
traitlets                 4.3.2                     <pip>
wcwidth                   0.1.7                     <pip>
wheel                     0.31.1                   py35_1    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4
zlib                      1.2.11               hf3cbc9b_2
```

Comment: Did you have the same environment when you installed it and imported it ?

Comment: @Agile_Eagle Yeah, installed into an environment called grib and activated ipython from within that environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `pip`? If you import it via IDLE, but installed it via conda, it won't work. If you want a specific version, download the tarball (.tar) and set it up your self.

Then again, the import name may be different.

Comment: WEIRD. so I was trying to import it through ipython, which wasn't working. but just starting python from the command line and importing it there seems to have worked fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MaxCaudle You need to install IPython into that environment as well.

Comment: Hm, Ipython is working fine in this environment (and is installed in the conda list). still can't import pygrib to ipython though

Comment: @MaxCaudle Can you edit the output of `conda list` for this environment into the question?

Comment: @darthbith added the output to the question